# Avoid memory fragmentation in high performance server sockets

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, buffer

I've been looking into using the new async socket functionality in .net 3.5, and I think I understand the concepts of using a large preallocated buffer pool in order to prevent memory fragmentation, and performance decrease from GC processing the buffers.

While thinking about all of this however, I got concerned about the way I actually save the data from the buffers until the entire message is received. Currently, on each receive, I append the received data onto a pending message object (a stringbuilder in some implementations, and another byte array in others).

Are these byte arrays safe since they never get marshalled to unmanaged code? Or is there a common approach used to retain data across multiple receives in order to build the complete message for processing?

Comment: Are the packets you receive of fixed size or are they variable? Maybe just a bit of code may help with the context.

Comment: I don't have code available yet, as I've just started researching this and kind of designing it out in my head. I know that the packets will be variable length, could be larger than a single buffer, the connections will be long lived, rather than a high volume of very short lived connections, and the incoming request rate will be fairly high.